# Amplify a 12 MHz sine wave

Tags: power, transformer, design, signal-processing

I need to take a 12MHz AC sine wave, from around 3.3V - 10V @ 10uA, output 50V, @ 1A (or more).

I have the signal generator for signal input, but I am not certain what I need for a circuit to step that up to the appropriate power level. And what if any isolation and OCPD I might need to protect my control circuit.

Should I use a toroidal transformer? Something else? Can someone point me to a specific device or module that I can buy?

Comment: What you are looking for is an "RF power amplifier", and they're commonly available. You need one that's rated for at least 50W (50 Vrms * 1 Arms).

Comment: I found parts, and I submitted a pair of designs for approval. Thanks Dave, for helping with what words to look for.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, as you view it. Conservation of energy

IN:  10V*10uA == 100uW

OUT: 50*1A = 50W.

You will need a power amplifier to take the small-signal AC to increase the power capability

Comment: yeah, which one? or should I amplify  that signal, then step it up? I need parts. Please Advise. I can add supplemental power no problem.

Comment: you would need an amp that could source >5A at 12MHz. A classAB could do it if you could manage the losses.